# Abort thread(s) gracefully when condition has been met?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Let's say I have two separate (mutually exclusive?) threads that I launch, with a notification at the end to notify that everything completed.

Is this a graceful way to abort threads that go beyond some condition? I use Framework 4.

Thanks.

```
 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
 DateTime StartNow = DateTime.Now;
 Thread thread = new Thread(() => RunsLongTime());
 thread.Start();
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => RunsEvenLonger());
 thread1.Start();
 DateTime RightNow = DateTime.Now;

 for (; ; )
 {
     if (RightNow >= StartNow.AddHours(1)) // A condition
     {
         thread.Abort();
         thread1.Abort();
         Console.WriteLine("ABORTED AT: " + DateTime.Now);
         break;
     }
     RightNow = DateTime.Now;
 }
```

Comment: It depends. Can you change the code that the threads are running? Do they spend the majority of their time running code under your control or are they spending their entire time inside some third party/framework code?

Comment: Yes, I can change the code that the threads are running.

Comment: There is no *graceful aborting*. Anything *bad* (`Exception`, `goto`) is better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious thing to do is to use [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - which produces a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the threads can monitor and respond to.

You can either initialize it with a timeout value when its constructed, or you can just call `Cancel` when its time for the threads to exit.

See [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details on this **cooperative** cancellation model. The only clean/graceful way for this to work is a cooperative one. Before .NET 4, various ad-hoc ways could be used (e.g. `ManualResetEvent`s) but now that `CancellationToken` has been baked into many APIs, it's the best (current) way to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It works well in the example. If the _long tasks_ were copying files, is there any difference between thread.abort() and CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()? There's really no clean-up, just stop copying files.

Comment: If *at all* possible, use the `CancellationToken` approach - it's the safe habit to get into because you *know* that the target thread is in the correct state (I.e. it was ready to respond to cancellation). `Thread.Abort` rips the floor out from under the thread. Since you asked for a graceful approach, then as I say in my answer, the *only* graceful approach is a cooperative one.

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RunForever), cts.Token);` But if method `RunForever(Object obj, string AnotherParm)` takes Object parameter and a string, how can I add that parameter when I do the call in this case?

Comment: I ended up with `new Thread(() => RunForever(cts.Token, AnotherParm)).Start();`